# Can I "Export Accounts" via command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

Using Xcode 9 to export a developer profile (.p12, provisioning profiles, etc.) and import it onto another Mac is simple enough, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it via command line?

I'd like to be able to SSH to my Mac at the office, for example, and pull them into my laptop when I'm away.

Comment: The way you wrote it made it seem like you have the need to do it often. I work on two different machines, but I only need to import / export when for some reason I revoke my certificate, that is, almost never. Am I missing something?

Comment: I only need to do it right now because I don't have access to the Mac, as I'm away from the office.  I can RDP to my PC at the office, which can see the Mac an should be able to SSH and run a command from there, assuming it can be done with a command line at all.